# Iteratively removing rows in pandas based on values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have to do  pre-processing on a series of DataFrames containing some measurements. Firstly, I need to remove the columns that I don't need, then I have to progressively assign a value to each row in each dataframe, increasing the value everytime I encounter the value '1111111'. After I'm done with this, I want to remove the NaN columns and the rows that contain the value with all ones.

This is how I was doing it

```
frames = [df_JSON, df_CBOR, df_mSEED, df_bSEED]
samples=[250, 500, 1000, 2000, 4000, 8000, 16000, 32000, 64000]

for df in frames:
    
    df.drop(df.columns[5:], axis=1, inplace=True) #drop columns that are not needed
    
    df['samples']='' #create a new column for the new values to assign to each row
    counter=0
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row['tg']!=11111111: #if the 11111111 value has not been encountered yet
                                #place the new value in the 'samples' column
            row['samples']=samples[counter] 
            df.iloc[index]=row
        else: 
            counter+=1 #otherwise change the value to the next one in the list
    df.dropna(axis=1, inplace=True) #remove the NaN columns
    rslt_df=df.loc[df['tg']!=11111111] #select the rows that do not contain the 11111111 value
    df=rslt_df #overwrite the old dataframe with the new one that does not contain the 11111111 value
```

Everything works but the overwriting at the end. Not being the most proficient user in pandas, I don't know if there are better ways to do it, or if I'm missing some aspect about assigning values to dataframes.

This is what I obtain in the end

```
              tg        tp        tr     t_TOT samples
    0      199100   2652300    700400   3551800     250
    1      137700   2600600    844200   3582500     250
    2       71200   2262700    632000   2965900     250
    3       83700   2202200    688700   2974600     250
    4       75800   2150900    703000   2929700     250
    ..        ...       ...       ...       ...     ...
    904   3811000  20121900   5447100  29380000   64000
    905   3605200  20780800   5357900  29743900   64000
    906   3955700  19300900   5390200  28646800   64000
    907   3838300   9793900   6258500  19890700   64000
    908  11111111  11111111  11111111  11111111   11111111
```

which is the end result I want, but with the extra 11111111 rows.

EDIT:

This is a test script to run my code.

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('testdata.xlsx')
df_JSON = pd.read_excel(xls, 1)
df_CBOR = pd.read_excel(xls, 2)
df_mSEED = pd.read_excel(xls, 3)
df_bSEED = pd.read_excel(xls, 4)

frames = [df_JSON, df_CBOR, df_mSEED, df_bSEED]

samples=[250, 500, 1000, 2000, 4000, 8000, 16000, 32000, 64000]

for df in frames:
    
    df.drop(df.columns[5:], axis=1, inplace=True) #drop columns that are not needed
    
    df['samples']='' #create a new column with the new value to assign to the row
    counter=0
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row['tg']!=11111111: #if the 11111111 value has not been encountered yet
                                #place the new value in the samples column
            row['samples']=samples[counter] 
            df.iloc[index]=row
        else: 
            counter+=1 #otherwise change the value to the next one in the list
    df.dropna(axis=1, inplace=True) #remove the NaN columns
    rslt_df=df.loc[df['tg']!=11111111] #select the rows that do not contain the 11111111 value
    df=rslt_df #overwrite the dataframe
```

Some test data can be found here https://wetransfer.com/downloads/9bb4468aced7db005390a8783165233c20220908123527/f9a4eb

Comment: you have few different tasks - so split it into separated problems and ask separated question. And you could use `print()` afte every task to see if it work correctly. And only one task gives wrong result then ask only for this task

Comment: it would be simpler if you would create minimal working code with example data in code - so we could simply copy and run it. At this moment code seems  good but we can't test your code.

Comment: I tried your code with some example data and I can't reproduce your problem. I never get extra row `11111111`. Maybe you have problem in different place or  maybe you have string `"11111111"` and it doesn't remove it. But with string `"11111111"` I get different value in column `samples`

Comment: Hi furas, thanks for the reply. I have edited the script with a sample code and a link to some sample data in the same format as my input data. I get the right result about the different values in column samples, but I'm still unable to update the dataframe with the new version that does not contain "11111111" rows.